# How to crop a photo in a storyboard (Xcode)

Tags: xcode

I have an image that is part of a vertical stack view (which includes a label and button), and there is a lot of blank space around the image. I was wondering if there was a way to get rid of this empty space so that the label and button are much closer to the actual image. Thank you!

[image: Picture of my storyboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set an `Aspect Ratio` constraint. Like so:

[image: Add New Constraints]
[image: Adjust constraints]

Set the aspect ratio to `1:1` to get a square. This will prevent your circle image view from expanding to a rectangle.